# Keywords arguments Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def keyword_arguments(**keywords):
    return sorted(keywords.keys())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print keyword_arguments(arg1 = 1, arg2 = 2, arg3 = 3)
```

the above code returns ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'] correctly. However, if I replace the return statement in the function like so:

```
return keywords.keys().sort()
```

it returns None. Why is this?

Comment: Because `sort` returns `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `sort()` returns `None`. It just sorts the list *in place*. You should do:

```
return sorted(keywords.keys())
```

#### Demonstration

```
a = [2,3,1]
>>> print a.sort()
None
>>> print a
[1, 2, 3]
```

### Alternative

```
a = keywords.keys()
a.sort()
return a
```

Comment: Why not return `keywords` and leave out `a`

Comment: `return a` will still return `None` in that example

Comment: @TimCastelijns, Because the dictionary would still remain unsorted

Comment: @TimCastelijns, I agree, but when you do `keyword.keys()`, you are getting the dictionary keys as a separate list, Then you would sort them and then they just get discarded. You still end up returning the unordered dictionary keys because the next time you do `keyword.keys()` for returning them, it takes them from the dictionary again.

Comment: Yes I got confused after your edit :-P already removed that comment

Comment: While the info is there, it is not well explained.